# Getting checkbox values from ListView

Tags: android

I have a listview of  that's tied to an array adapter.  For the life of me I can't figure out how to get a list of the checked boxes in the listview.

```
CheckViewArrayAdapter adapter;
    int[] intarray;

    paramListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.datalog_paramselectlist);

    // get all supported params
    intarray = ConMan.Ecu.getSupportedParamArrayVals();

    LinkedHashMap<Integer,String> hm = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,String>();

    for( x=0;x<intarray.length;x++){
         hm.put(intarray[x] , ConMan.Ecu.paramToText(intarray[x]));
    }

    adapter = new CheckViewArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice , android.R.id.text1, hm);
    adapter.setBoolArray(ConMan.Ecu.getSelectedParamFlagArray());


    // Assign adapter to ListView
    paramListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I have a setOnItemClickListener for paramListView that works, but I just want to get the final set of checked checkboxes when the screen exits.  I simply don't know where to look.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a setOnItemClickListener for paramListView that works, but I just want to get the final set of checkboxes when the screen exits.

I assume that you are not setting the choice mode for your ListView. If you do use:

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

then in your `onPause()` method, you can ask for an index of the checked rows with [`ListView#getCheckedItemPosition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#getCheckedItemPositions%28%29) and you don't need to change the checked state manually in your OnItemClickListener.